# For loop with select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for @score do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :site_id %> 
    <%= f.select(:value, [['1', 1], ['2', 2], ['3', 3], ['4', 4]]) %>       
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to have the select values go all the way up to 10, but I don't want to manually put them in there.

Is there a way to DRY that line up? Or will have I have to manually put 10 elements inside that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're just singular values, `select` can deal with that:

```
<%= f.select(:value, (1..10).to_a) %>
```

If you care about having string/number pairs:

```
<%= f.select(:value, (1..10).collect {|n| [ n.to_s, n ] }) %>
```